# My wordpress built in (php) functions are not being read within visual studio code. Anyone know how to fix this?

Tags: php, wordpress

The built in php wordpress functions are not reading in my VScode and its really bugging me because it is showing yellow/orange swiggly lines.

```
    <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
    <?php the_content();?>
    <hr>
<?php }

get_footer();
?>
```

Word Press functions not registering in VScode

[image: Word Press functions not registering in VScode]

Comment: Might be related to this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59890854/vs-code-highlighted-all-my-wordpress-function-name

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to install a specific extension:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=johnbillion.vscode-wordpress-hooks

Comment: I downloaded it but it still says "call to unknown function" on all WordPress related functions.

Comment: Try with one of these solutions from a previous discussion: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59890854/vs-code-highlighted-all-my-wordpress-function-name

Answer (score 1):

if this could help someone facing the same issue, here is what worked for me:

1. download PHP_Intelephense [Here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bmewburn.vscode-intelephense-client) if not already installed.
2. Then in VsCode go to : settings (ctr+,)  > Extensions >Intelephense,

then find your intelephense.stubs, add Wordpress and save changes.
[See this screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GeqBy.jpg)

3. Restart your VsCode and Voila !

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. It turns out I needed to open the PHP files in my root folder in order for the WordPress functions to be acknowledged by VScode.